# Dataset Crystal Report crash

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

NET application that was running on Windows Server 2003 and now it's been upgraded to Windows Server 2012.

The application has several report made in Crystal Report and whenever those reports are fed a dataset I get the following error:

```
Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\temp_8906e55c-36b9-40f1-8385-7bf2fafe324c {9D8F44CC-FC36-4F28-916B-DAD28922C786}.rpt:
The request could not be submitted for background processing.

[COMException (0x800002ad): 
Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\temp_8906e55c-36b9-40f1-8385-7bf2fafe324c {9D8F44CC-FC36-4F28-916B-DAD28922C786}.rpt:
The request could not be submitted for background processing.]
  CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseControllerClass.ReplaceConnection(Object oldConnection, Object newConnection, Object parameterFields, Object crDBOptionUseDefault) +0
  CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.SetDataSource(Object val, Type type) +1084



CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type) +280

[InternalException: 
Error in File C:\Windows\TEMP\temp_8906e55c-36b9-40f1-8385-7bf2fafe324c {9D8F44CC-FC36-4F28-916B-DAD28922C786}.rpt:
The request could not be submitted for background processing.]


CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e) +789
  CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type) +327
  CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSource(DataSet dataSet) +91
  CCD.Tresorerie.SWAP.Reports.ReportExtensions.SetSQLQuery(ReportClass report, ReportQuery query) in C:\ProjetTFS\SWAP\DEV\merciera[ReHmai2015]\Sources\CCD.Tresorerie.SWAP.Reports\ReportExtensions.cs:80
  CCD.Tresorerie.SWAP.Reports.ReportExtensions.SetSQLQuery(ReportClass report, List`1 queries) in C:\ProjetTFS\SWAP\DEV\merciera[ReHmai2015]\Sources\CCD.Tresorerie.SWAP.Reports\ReportExtensions.cs:70
  CCD.Tresorerie.SWAP.BusinessProcessor.ReportHelper.SetReportPropertyMeta(ReportProperties reportProperty, ReportClass report) in C:\ProjetTFS\SWAP\DEV\merciera[ReHmai2015]\Sources\CCD.Tresorerie.SWAP.BusinessProcessor\ReportHelper.cs:23
  CCD.Tresorerie.SWAP.App.Web.Rapports.ShowReportViewer.ShowReport(eReport reportName) in C:\ProjetTFS\SWAP\DEV\merciera[ReHmai2015]\Sources\CCD.Tresorerie.SWAP.App.Web\Rapports\ShowReportViewer.aspx.cs:646
  CCD.Tresorerie.SWAP.App.Web.Rapports.ShowReportViewer.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\ProjetTFS\SWAP\DEV\merciera[ReHmai2015]\Sources\CCD.Tresorerie.SWAP.App.Web\Rapports\ShowReportViewer.aspx.cs:45
  System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
  System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
  System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e) +132
  System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e) +16
  System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +143
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1477
```

I am feeding the dataset to the report as such :

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.Tables.Add(ToDataTable<RistournesAD>(ristournes)); 
 ds.Tables[0].TableName = "RistournesAD"; 
 rapport.SetDataSource(ds);
```

It is important to denote that on the Windows server 2003 there are no errors when generating the reports in the application. All the reports that were using a stored procedure are still working perfectly fine. We rewrote a few reports to change the datasource from dataset to stored procedure and those reports begun working again.

As a temporary fix, in the IIS hosting the application we setted Enable 32-bit applications to true in the application pool. After this the reports using datasets were working properly. I would want to avoid doing this as the goal of running the application on winserver 2008 was to run them as 64bits applications.

I have looked at all the articles that I could find online and none of them were of any help. Let me know if I can provide any additional information to fix this problem.

Thank you

Comment: This is an old question, but I had the same issue some time ago. I haven't found any solution to this, therefore I simply rewrote the reports to take data from database instead.